# Python is using dict.update not type safe if passing in a TypedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, mypy, static-typing

From reading through `mypy` issues, it seems as if calling `dict.update()`, and supplying a `TypedDict` is not type safe.  This does not make sense to me.

My question is (particularly from the 2nd issue, linked below):

- Since a `TypedDict` is a `dict` at runtime, why does `mypy` complain about not being able to pass a `TypedDict` into `dict.update`, saying it expects a `Mapping`?

  - In my mind, `dict` is like saying `Dict[Any, Any]`, so why not add a `TypedDict` as a dict value?
  - In your answer,can you please provide a concrete example?
- In general, why is calling `dict.update(SomeTypedDict)` not type safe?

---

There are two examples of this, found in `mypy` issues:

1. [python/mypy #6462](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6462): TypedDict update() does not accept TypedDict with compatible subset keys

> This is a pretty subtle issue. The update call is arguably not type safe.

2. [python/mypy #9086](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9086): False positive [arg-type] error when updating a dict with a TypedDict

> Since TypedDict objects use structural subtyping, there could be additional items not visible through the type `Foo`, with arbitrary value types. Thus `Mapping[str, object]` is correct (though it is unintuitive).

---

**Sample Code** from [python/mypy #9086](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9086)

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    baz: int

foo: Foo = {"baz": 9000}

# spam is a regular dict, yet mypy errors out when trying to add a TypedDict
# to it.  This doesn't make sense to me, when a regular dict should be like
# saying equal Dict[Any, Any]
spam = {"ham": {"eggs": 5}}
spam["ham"].update(foo)  # error: Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has
# incompatible type "Foo"; expected "Mapping[str, int]"  [arg-type]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#id20) says that:

> First, any `TypedDict` type is consistent with `Mapping[str, object]`. Second, a `TypedDict` type A is consistent with `TypedDict` B if A is structurally compatible with B.

> A `TypedDict` with all int values is not consistent with `Mapping[str, int]`, **since there may be additional non-int values not visible through the type, due to structural subtyping. These can be accessed using the values() and items() methods in Mapping, for example.**

Example:

```py
class A(TypedDict):
    x: int

class B(TypedDict):
    x: int
    y: str

def sum_values(m: Mapping[str, int]) -> int:
    n = 0
    for v in m.values():
        n += v  # Runtime error
    return n

def f(a: A) -> None:
    sum_values(a)  # Error: 'A' incompatible with Mapping[str, int]

b: B = {'x': 0, 'y': 'foo'}
f(b)
```

---

Update: Let us consider your sample

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    baz: int

foo: Foo = {"baz": 9000}

# spam here is not equal Dict[Any, Any]. mypy will infer type for it 
# as Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]. Consequently, update() method for its 
# item below will expect Mapping[str, int]  
spam = {"ham": {"eggs": 5}}
# If you try to do empty dict as below which indeed has type Dict[Any, Any]
# spam = {}  # mypy will complain on it "Need type annotation for 'spam'"
spam["ham"].update(foo)  # error: Argument 1 to "update" of "dict" has 
# incompatible type "Foo"; expected "Mapping[str, int]"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example.  It's similar to the example in PEP 589, I agree that it makes sense that `mypy` raises an error.  However, I think you're misunderstanding my question.  My question was about passing a `TypedDict` into `dict.update`, not about trying to type hint methods with `TypedDict` subclasses.  If a `TypedDict` is consistent with `Mapping[str, object]`, then I see no reason why I can't pass that into the `update` method of a plain `dict`.  Why would that be considered not type safe?

Comment: Modified answer